# Iupred definition of long/short form disorder

Tags: software-recommendation

I need to predict disorder of proteins and [here](http://d2p2.pro/about/predictors) there is a description of [Iupred](https://iupred2a.elte.hu) in its two variants, **long** and **short**-disorder. [This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022283605001294?via%3Dihub) is a manuscript defining the method. I couldn't find a precise definition of short or long-disorder.

I need to predict disorder in **30-mers**, but I expect that as with secondary structure prediction, the longer the input sequence the more accurate the result.

I will appreciate if anyone has experience with this software and can share ideas or suggestion on how to proceed.